# WSO2 IS 5.9 Error when creating Secondary User Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have changed the default user store from LDAP to JDBC, and after that change, I cannot create secondary user stores based on LDAP. I always get the following error when creating it in the form:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 14:32:42,848] [9e6d0a88-08a4-46ad-9846-0b392378abcb] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - too much data for RSA block java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.stub.UserStoreConfigAdminServiceStub.editUserStore(UserStoreConfigAdminServiceStub.java:600)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.ui.client.UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.updateUserStore(UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.java:206)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.ui.client.UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.updateUserStoreWithDomainName(UserStoreConfigAdminServiceClient.java:193)
    at org.apache.jsp.userstore_005fconfig.userstore_002dconfig_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(userstore_002dconfig_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:241)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of the secondary user store configs? Also, have you touched your keystores by any chance?

Comment: Either, your connection password is really long. or you've made some changes to the default keystore. As a workaroound you can add the user store from the file system with encryption disabled. So that you won't face this issue

Comment: What is your private key length and the secondary userstore password length?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above. Disable the user store in the UI and then edit the corresponding XML file in the 'userstores' directory and remove the encrypted=true setting from the password. Re-enter the password in plaintext and then go back to the UI and re-enable the user store. You can just edit the file without enabling/disabling, but this approach is much cleaner and will give you good log output.